# Draw segmented line graphs of pandas data frame with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wanted to draw line graphs of a data frame which is segmented by horizontal axis values defined by `line_segments_by_X`. Any ideas how can I do it with Matplotlib?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line_segments_by_X = [(1,2), (3,4)]

data = {"X": list(x for x in range(5)), "V0": list(x for x in range(10, 15)),
    "V1": list(x for x in range(20, 25))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["X", "V0", "V1"])

ax = plt.gca()
df.plot(kind='line', x='X', y="V0", ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line', x='X', y="V1", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Something I am intending to get is as in the picture. [image]

Comment: What is the error you facing?

Comment: The figure is intended, Code is for thr continuous lines from where I want to create thr segments.

Comment: what is thr?? Lines depends on x and y coordinates data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following? It should work for an arbitrary list of line segments. Let's set up the problem as you did:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line_segments_by_X = [(1,2), (3,4)]

data = {"X": list(x for x in range(5)),
        "V0": list(x for x in range(10, 15)),
        "V1": list(x for x in range(20, 25))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["X", "V0", "V1"])
```

Here I create the figure and axis to plot on, and then loop over each segment.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for segment in line_segments_by_X:
    # Bool of values in segment
    bool = (df['X'] >= segment[0]) & (df['X'] <= segment[1])
    # Use bool to plot the lines in this segment
    ax.plot(df['X'][bool], df['V0'][bool], c='C0', label='V0')
    ax.plot(df['X'][bool], df['V1'][bool], c='C1', label='V1')
```

In looping over the segments I've actually added each label to the legend twice. Let's ensure that each label only occurs once, and label your x axis:

```py
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))
ax.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())

ax.set_xlabel('x')
```

This gave me the plot below:

[image]